# React native animated flatlist within tab and head view

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I gonna implement below component by using react native.
[image]

in this page, we have header view and tab menu and, each tab include flatlist.
When scroll down flatlist in tab, header view is hidden as animated.
[image]

we have to keep tab bar .
I have been implemented one header view + one animatedflast list compoent action.
But, my required result is tab-flatlist.
Is there solution for it?

Comment: have you considered this library "https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view" ? it's good, but a bit glitchy on android though.

Comment: Thanks. But, I am meaning, Animate shrinking header with tabs and faltlist in tab effect such as google player list

Answer (score 0):

spotify app does that too with the music/album list, i tried to do it with animation and js, but the performance wasn't that great, it just wasn't snappy, my advice is to to have 2 scrollviews inside each other, outer one containing the header and the second(inner) scrollview below the header, and the inner scrollview should be the flatlist. 
What should happen is that when you scroll, the outer scrollview will scroll first and when reaches end the inner one will start scrolling.

```
<ScrollView> <== outer scrollview
 <header/>
 <ScrollView> <== inner scrollview(should be a flatlist in your case)
   <FlatList/>
 </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: tx for your help.

Comment: But, in inner scollview, is it possible to apply onendreach function into flatlist?

Comment: @Benny Sudibyo yes you can, btw, there is a minor detail i missed, since you want it the items listed in a flatlist, it's best to have the inner scrollview as a flatlist component.(i updated the answer)

Comment: @BennySudibyo could you mark this answer as a solution if it worked for you ? :)

Comment: 1. when i drag in flatlist area, only flatlist is scrolled, outer scroll doesn't occure.

Comment: 2. I can not trigger  endreach in flatlist.

Comment: Did anyone reach a solution for having FlatLists inside a ScrollView?